# Create Azure AD dynamic group with service principals as memebers

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is any way I can create a dynamic Azure AD group with service principals as dynamic members? I can only select users which is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is impossible.

Please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/6688284-ad-groups-in-application-owners). If you really need this, you could vote up this feedback.

Comment: Hi, please let me know if you need more future help.